# Set the database as read_only

Tags: azure-sql-database

From this article  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx

there's a note tip:

> You are charged for each `database copy`. To avoid additional charges for the copies, you can set the database as `read-only`, and export a `BACPAC file` directly from the `database` to create a `transitionally consistent copy`. However marking the `database` as `read-only` `locks the database access until the export is complete` and `the read-only settings are reverted`."

but how we can set the sql azure database to `read-only`?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 11):

You can make database read only by using the following query.
I am not sure about the charging of Read-Only Data bases in SQL Azure

**Make Database Read Only**

```
--USE [master]
--GO
ALTER DATABASE [TESTDB] SET READ_ONLY WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

**Make Database Read/Write**

```
--USE [master]
--GO
ALTER DATABASE [TESTDB] SET READ_WRITE 
GO
```

I got this from the [SQL_Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/16/sql-server-making-database-to-read-only-changing-database-to-readwrite/), check the same for more details.

**Edit:**

> USE [master] will not work in Azure Environment.

You can change connection to use [master] database.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute below command by connecting to the database you want to modify / master database.
    alter database  ser read_only | read_write